# Is there any way to lock my mac without sleeping and without the screen saver activating?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, settings, screen-lock

I want my Mac to stay awake on the login screen, but without activating the screen saver.

I have tried a lot to no avail. I have tried to change Energy Saver settings, which only take effect when I'm logged in.

After press `Control + Command + Q`, these settings no longer apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the screen saver on the login window with this command in Terminal:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver loginWindowIdleTime 0
```

The settings you have in "Energy Saver Settings" are only for the logged in user, whereas the login screen runs in a different context. To change the settings for the login window context, use the command above.